# Problema al leer un archivo con open()

Tags: perl

Mi problema es que tengo un fichero de texto llamado datos.txt el cual contiene esto:

```
Hola Mundo
Bienvenidos a este espacio
Programacion Perl
```

Y tengo un script en Perl el cual abre el archivo para leerlo; este es el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(ARCHIVO,"datos.txt");
my $archivo = <ARCHIVO>;
print $archivo;
```

El problema que tengo es que sólo se lee la primera línea. ¿Cómo haría para leer todas las líneas del archivo datos.txt?

Cómo podría solucionarlo de forma sencilla, ya que apenas estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador diamante, en contexto escalar sólo devuelve una línea del archivo. En ese caso debes hacer un bucle while por todo el archivo para leerlo línea a línea.

Otra opción es ejecutar el operador en contexto lista y así te devuelve todas las líneas del archivo, un elemento por cada línea. Así:

```
my @archivo = <ARCHIVO>;
```

Tienes más información con el comando `perldoc perldata`.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias me funciono

Comment: Revise las páginas perldoc y perldata, pero la documentación aparece es en inglés, no habrá alguna página en donde salga en español

Comment: Sí, los tienes aquí: https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/tree/master/pod/translated Tienes que buscar en ```perlfunc```, por la función ```readline```.

Comment: Muchas gracias se lo agradezco bastante 